SwiftでFirebaseを初期化しようとするとクラッシュする
アプリ作成初学者です。
SwiftとFirebaseを使ってスマホで録音したデータをFirebaseにアップロードするアプリ(アプリ名:Uploadmusic)を作ろうとしました。
しかし、公式ドキュメントに沿ってアプリでFirebaseを初期化しようとしたところ、ContentViewのプレビューが毎回Cannnot preview in this file (Uploadmusic may have crashed)となります。
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
この一文を入れるとCrashするのですが、どこに問題があるのでしょうか？
Xcode version 16.1
Firebase version 11.5.0
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: 166AC499-4D8D-4698-A875-85C6DAFBF06B
CrashReporter Key:   2C217202-D05E-9E98-D71B-75204D0F7B73
Hardware Model:      MacBookAir10,1
Process:             Uploadmusic [30394]
Path:                /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/Previews/Simulator Devices/9086415E-8124-4A87-A54E-5F948444F96C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/163481AF-EDD6-4EFE-894F-30378F264389/Uploadmusic.app/Uploadmusic
Identifier:          com.example.Uploadmusic
Version:             1.0 (1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [27620]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.9086415E-8124-4A87-A54E-5F948444F96C [168313]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [81690]

Date/Time:           2024-11-20 09:35:53.1242 +0900
Launch Time:         2024-11-20 09:35:51.6907 +0900
OS Version:          macOS 14.5 (23F79)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: Uploadmusic [30394]

Triggered by Thread:  0


追記)20241125
GoogleService-Infoのアップロードがうまく行っていなかったみたいで、Firebaseからダウンロードをしなおしたら治りました。ご協力ありがとうございました
